# AppleScript: Garbage values written to file when using path to command

Tags: applescript, writetofile

I am trying to write a simple applescript that organises the files in any selected folder. I want to make the script such that it runs at specific intervals and re-organizes the folder if something has changed. For this, I am trying to save the path of the user chosen folder to a file. Each time the script runs, it reads the folder path from this file.

here's a snippet from the code:

```
set home_path to get path to home folder

tell application "Finder"
    set home_folder to folder (home_path as string)
    if not (exists file "Clfd_config.cf1" in home_folder) then
        set (folder_path) to choose folder with prompt "Choose the folder to organize"
        set this_folder to folder (folder_path as string)
        set path_file to open for access file (home_path & "Clfd_config.cf1" as text) with write permission
        write folder_path to path_file
        close access path_file
    else
        set path_file to open for access file (home_path & "Clfd_config.cf1" as   string)
        set folder_path to read path_file as string
        set this_folder to folder (folder_path as string)
        close access path_file

    end if
end tell
```

However, when I open the file, it has garbled information, like so:

```
������Harshad��������������������œ‘xH+���   7    Desktop�����������������������������������������    ����������������   7Éœ‘zç��������ˇˇˇˇ��I ����������    ������œ‘*∆������œ‘-5������D�e�s�k�t�o�p���    �H�a�r�s�h�a�d��Users/harshad/Desktop���/����ˇˇ������
```

When I try to read this file n the script, the script obviously fails.

I have tried telling the script to write the file as string, as text, but I keep getting the error that the folder_path variable cannot be converted to text or string.

What should I do so that the path is saved properly and the script can read it back from the saved file?

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is that you're writing an alias file specifier to disk rather than a string path.

I added basic error handling while writing to disk and removed some redundant code

```
property configFileName : "Clfd_config.cf1"

tell application "Finder"
    set configFile to (home as text) & configFileName
    if not (exists file configFile) then
        set folder_path to choose folder with prompt "Choose the folder to organize"
        try
            set fileReference to open for access file configFile with write permission
            write (folder_path as text) to fileReference
            close access fileReference
        on error
            try
                close access file configFile
            end try
        end try
    else
        set folder_path to read file configFile
        set this_folder to folder folder_path
    end if
end tell
```

Comment: Thanks vadian, this works perfectly well. However, I have hit a snag while trying to read the file. the compiler is hitting eof prematurely, and the folder_path only reads up to 10 characters from the file. For now, I have done "set folder_path to read file configFile before 15" and its reading the whole thing now.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you just want to save value of a folder path and be able to find it again during next run.
if only that, why are you using subroutine to write this path to a text file at specific place ? isn't it easier to you use the characteristics of "property" objects ?

"Property" variable can be changed and it keeps new value in the script itself, until next compilation.

Try this script bellow : the first run, it will ask you for folder. Select it. Any next run, it will just display the folder selected during first run !

```
property My_Folder : ""
if My_Folder is "" then -- first run, ask user to select folder
    Set My_Folder to (choose folder with prompt "choose the folder to organise") as string
end if
display dialog "folder selected = " & My_Folder
```

it does the same thing than read/write  from text file...

Comment: this is only reliable if the script is saved as application. At the moment a normal .scpt file is re-compiled the property is reset to its default value.